# apche ignite client and server configuration for production

Tags: java, spring-boot, ignite

I have done below server configuration for ignite.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       ">
    <description>Main Spring file for ignite configuration.</description>

    <bean id="cacheIgniteBean" class="org.apache.ignite.IgniteSpringBean">
        <property name="configuration">
            <bean id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
                <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
                        <property name="dataRegionConfigurations">
                            <list>

                                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">

                                    <property name="name" value="item_cache_Region"/>

                                    <property name="initialSize" value="${ignite.config.item.cache.initialSize}"/>

                                    <property name="maxSize" value="${ignite.config.item.cache.maxSize}"/>

                                    <property name="pageEvictionMode" value="RANDOM_LRU"/>
                                </bean>

                                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                                    <property name="name" value="location_cache_Region"/>

                                    <property name="initialSize" value="${ignite.config.location.cache.initialSize}"/>

                                    <property name="maxSize" value="${ignite.config.location.cache.maxSize}"/>

                                    <property name="pageEvictionMode" value="RANDOM_LRU"/>

                                    <property name="persistenceEnabled"
                                              value="${ignite.config.cache.location.native.persistence.enabled}"/>

                                </bean>

                                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">

                                    <property name="name" value="order_cache_Region"/>

                                    <property name="initialSize" value="${ignite.config.order.cache.initialSize}"/>

                                    <property name="maxSize" value="${ignite.config.order.cache.maxSize}"/>

                                    <property name="pageEvictionMode" value="RANDOM_LRU"/>

                                </bean>


                            </list>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
                <property name="cacheConfiguration">
                    <list>
                        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">

                            <property name="name" value="item"/>
                            <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED"/>
                            <property name="atomicityMode" value="ATOMIC"/>
                            <property name="backups" value="0"/>
                            <property name="cacheStoreFactory">
                                <bean class="javax.cache.configuration.FactoryBuilder" factory-method="factoryOf">
                                    <constructor-arg value="com.tgt.gom.cacheserver.store.ItemCacheStore"/>
                                </bean>
                            </property>
                            <property name="readThrough" value="${ignite.config.cache.item.readThrough}"/>
                            <property name="writeThrough" value="${ignite.config.cache.item.writeThrough}"/>
                            <property name="writeBehindEnabled" value="${ignite.config.cache.item.writeBehindEnabled}"/>
                            <property name="writeBehindFlushSize"
                                      value="${ignite.config.cache.item.writeBehindFlushSize}"/>
                            <property name="writeBehindFlushFrequency"
                                      value="${ignite.config.cache.item.writeBehindFlushFrequency}"/>
                            <property name="writeBehindFlushThreadCount"
                                      value="${ignite.config.cache.item.writeBehindFlushThreadCount}"/>
                            <property name="writeBehindBatchSize"
                                      value="${ignite.config.cache.item.writeBehindBatchSize}"/>

                            <property name="dataRegionName" value="item_cache_Region"/>

                        </bean>

                        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">

                            <property name="name" value="location"/>
                            <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED"/>
                            <property name="atomicityMode" value="ATOMIC"/>
                            <property name="backups" value="0"/>

                            <property name="dataRegionName" value="location_cache_Region"/>
                        </bean>

                        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">

                            <property name="name" value="order"/>
                            <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED"/>
                            <property name="atomicityMode" value="ATOMIC"/>
                            <property name="backups" value="0"/>
                            <property name="eagerTtl" value="true"/>
                            <property name="dataRegionName" value="order_cache_Region"/>
                        </bean>

                    </list>
                </property>

                <property name="failureDetectionTimeout" value="60000"/>
                <property name="discoverySpi">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                        <property name="ipFinder">
                            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                                <property name="addresses">
                                    <list>
                                        <value>127.0.0.1:47500..47505</value>
                                        <value>10.60.158.197:47500..47505</value>
                                        <value>10.60.158.196:47500..47505</value>
                                        <value>10.60.158.20:47500..47505</value>
                                        <value>10.60.158.2:47500..47505</value>
                                    </list>
                                </property>
                            </bean>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

and below client configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       ">
    <description>Main Spring file for ignite configuration.</description>

    <bean id="cacheIgniteBean" class="org.apache.ignite.IgniteSpringBean">
        <property name="configuration">
            <bean id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
                <property name="clientMode" value="true"/>
                <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
                        <property name="dataRegionConfigurations">
                            <list>
                                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">

                                    <property name="name" value="order_cache_Region"/>

                                    <property name="initialSize" value="${ignite.config.order.cache.initialSize}"/>

                                    <property name="maxSize" value="${ignite.config.order.cache.maxSize}"/>

                                    <property name="pageEvictionMode" value="RANDOM_LRU"/>

                                </bean>


                            </list>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
                <property name="cacheConfiguration">
                    <list>

                        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">

                            <property name="name" value="order"/>
                            <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED"/>
                            <property name="atomicityMode" value="ATOMIC"/>
                            <property name="backups" value="0"/>
                            <property name="eagerTtl" value="true"/>
                            <property name="dataRegionName" value="order_cache_Region"/>
                        </bean>

                    </list>
                </property>

                <property name="clientFailureDetectionTimeout" value="50000"/>
                <property name="failureDetectionTimeout" value="50000"/>

                <property name="discoverySpi">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                        <property name="networkTimeout" value="20000"/>
                        <property name="forceServerMode" value="${ignite.client.force.server.mode}"/>
                        <property name="ipFinder">
                            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                                <property name="addresses">
                                    <list>
                                        <value>10.60.158.197:47500..47505</value>
                                        <value>10.60.158.196:47500..47505</value>
                                        <value>10.60.158.20:47500..47505</value>
                                        <value>10.60.158.2:47500..47505</value>
                                    </list>
                                </property>
                            </bean>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I have 4 server nodes and 2 client nodes.Am i missing anything in configuration which may cause performance issues.I am getting below warnings sometime on client and server boxes.

server node warnings-:

```
e41fd3-846c-4086-a7bf-486616594368]","logger_name":"org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi","thread_name":"grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-2-#27","level":"INFO","level_value":20000}
{"@timestamp":"2018-02-08T23:36:22.177-05:00","@version":1,"message":"Accepted incoming communication connection [locAddr=/192.168.208.5:47100, rmtAddr=/192.168.208.10:58392]","logger_name":"org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi","thread_name":"grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-3-#28","level":"INFO","level_value":20000}
{"@timestamp":"2018-02-08T23:36:22.177-05:00","@version":1,"message":"Received incoming connection when already connected to this node, rejecting [locNode=434ef9a9-eb32-4096-8f80-843486a89137, rmtNode=65e41fd3-846c-4086-a7bf-486616594368]","logger_name":"org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi","thread_name":"grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-3-#28","level":"INFO","level_value":20000}
```

clent node warnings-:

```
{"@timestamp":"2018-02-08T23:27:30.904-05:00","@version":1,"message":"Found long running cache future [startTime=23:25:45.075, curTime=23:27:30.898, fut=GridPartitionedSingleGetFuture [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=10, minorTopVer=0], key=UserKeyCacheObjectImpl [part=239, val=20170627035520067938, hasValBytes=true], readThrough=true, forcePrimary=false, futId=a63a0367161-9c6368e5-8fa4-4550-abf6-02f8ef50125e, trackable=true, subjId=65e41fd3-846c-4086-a7bf-486616594368, taskName=null, deserializeBinary=true, skipVals=false, expiryPlc=CacheExpiryPolicy [], canRemap=true, needVer=false, keepCacheObjects=false, recovery=false, node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=434ef9a9-eb32-4096-8f80-843486a89137, addrs=[127.0.0.1, 192.168.208.5], sockAddrs=[/192.168.208.5:47500, /127.0.0.1:47500], discPort=47500, order=1, intOrder=1, lastExchangeTime=1518106106491, loc=false, ver=2.3.0#20171028-sha1:8add7fd5, isClient=false]]]","logger_name":"org.apache.ignite.internal.diagnostic","thread_name":"grid-timeout-worker-#23","level":"WARN","level_value":30000}



org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheStoppedException: Failed to perform cache operation (cache is stopped):
```

Can please anyone suggest anything if i am missing in configurations for production environments.?

And any idea about following metricLogs.

Metrics for local node (to disable set 'metricsLogFrequency' to 0)\n    ^-- Node [id=1c4d9a3e, uptime=15:49:04.761]\n    ^-- H/N/C [hosts=4, nodes=4, CPUs=16]\n    ^-- CPU [cur=0.17%, avg=0.27%, GC=0%]\n    ^-- PageMemory [pages=1624]\n    ^-- Heap [used=510MB, free=91.55%, comm=6036MB]\n    ^-- Non heap [used=117MB, free=-1%, comm=119MB]\n    ^-- Public thread pool [active=0, idle=0, qSize=0]\n    ^-- System thread pool [active=0, idle=6, qSize=0]\n    ^-- Outbound messages queue [size=0]","logger_name":"org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal","thread_name":"grid-timeout-worker-#23","level":"INFO","level_value":20000}

here it is saying that non heap memory free is -1%.In dataregion configuration i have given min 1 gb and max 2 gb memory.Any idea how to take care of this non heap memory?

Comment: Do you have a firewall between client and server?

Comment: @ValentinKulichenko ...Yes.but all the required ips are whitelisted and cluster is being formed correctly.Not sure still why warnings are there sometimes.

Comment: @ValentinKulichenko . i am seeing that some nodes get disconnected from cluster after 1 or 2 days.Do you have any idea what may be the reason based on my configuration.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like this issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-6818

It's fixed in 2.4 which will be released soon. I would recommend to monitor Ignite dev list for further announcements. You can also build from master to check it it resolves the issue or not.

Comment: @ValentinKulichenko..i have added one more query at the end of my question.Can you suggest anything about that?

Comment: Off-heap metrics are not fully implemented yet, there are multiple improvements in progress. Going forward, this should be a separate thread as it's not related to initial question. See this for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask